# Getting Output from Continuous (Unending) Terminal Programs in Java

Tags: java, bash, shell, terminal

Basically I'm running a program that takes continuous input. It doesn't end until you input an "@" symbol and press enter. I am wondering how I can read the output from this program, given that there is currently (what I have inferred is) a "readLine() block" when I try to get the BufferedReader content. Current code is below. I've done it with and without the while loop, and either way the program never reaches an end point, indicating to me it is the readLine() that is the problem.

An example of the program is something like
`input a number:
2
You input 2
input a number:
3
You input 3
input a number:
@
exit`

That isn't the program, but the basic gist of what it is and how it acts. I need to get every bit of that output. Input is another story; consider it irrelevant to the question for now, as I'm not even there just yet.

My code is below.

`ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
        Process p = pb.start();
        BufferedReader terminalOutput = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()) );
        BufferedWriter terminalInput = new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()) );
        String line = "";
        String s = "";
        int count = 0; 
        line = terminalOutput.readLine();`

Comment: Don't use `BufferedReader`?

Comment: I'd love to hear some possible alternatives. This is all I've seen people using.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Is there any chance you can whip up a runnable test case that shows the shows the program, its output and the output you expected? This makes it possible to reproduce for current and future readers, and helps take the guesswork out of what exactly the problem is.

Comment: There is no output. The program hangs. As I've said, the terminal process I'm trying to pull from with BufferedReader is a continuous, unending process that takes input from the user. I want to get the stdout of that terminal process. Should be extremely simple, but all I've seen are the typical "one-and-done" process stdout readings. That is, they aren't dealing with a terminal process that "keeps going" like I am. Their processes just do something, and end, and spit out their stdout - that's easy. My process never ends, and I still want its output. That's what I need.

Comment: You could take any process that does this sort of thing. Imagine a terminal process that does this:
<code>Please print your name:</code>
The program waits for you to print your name BEFORE ending; it is an unending, continuous program. Theoretically, my code would screw up on this hypothetical program in the same way. All I want is to grab that initial "Please print your name:" and add it to a string for further processing. Simple, right? Apparently not. That's why I'm asking your help. And remember, the program is STILL RUNNING at that point of "Please print your name." That's the difference.